# Concurrency through ExecutorService in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm using below concurrency feature of Java 1.6 to execute some task offline. When the user is created through registration, I need to perform some inhouse logging task & I don't want to block the user, so I've been using the below code

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService myservice = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    myservice.execute(new myTask(user));
```

Here, I'm having an inner class myTask which implements Runnable & in Run method, I'm doing offline activity (thus making it as a non-blocking call).

Now, once the user logs in to website, there are certain actions (buttons on web pages) clicking on which I need to do similar offline activities & I don't want to make the call as a blocking call. I've 4 actions on this page on which I need to perform offline tasks.

Is it ok to use the similar above code with 4 different inner classes & perform offline activity within them?? If not, whats the alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Executors if you are not expecting high level of concurrent requests. Use [Thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) in this case.

If yours is a highly-concurrent app and you should guarantee the processing of the action (even in case of jvm crash) and you want the actions to be transactional then messaging (JMS) might be the solution.

I've successfully used Executors with pools successfully earlier in a web-application. It is however not recommended to create threads in a web-app and not allowed in an EJB as the threads are not managed by the container.

**Example**

```
static final int POOL_SIZE=10;
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
```

You can also read this nice article: [Java Concurrency](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools)

Comment: I'm using Struts2 & within struts action, I've this executor thread. Would you be able to provide sample line on how to implement thread pool? Do I need to configure thread pool size? If so, where? I'm using tomcat 6 server.

Comment: @Mike added the sample code. you need to make sure you create the tread pool only once and shutdown before the webapp is shutdown.

Comment: I'm still new in using these API. I can see that you've invoked newFixedThreadPool. But then how will it call myTask which is my inner class which implements Runnable interface? Do I need to call pool.execute(new myTask(user)); Also, what happens if more than 10 users try to access website?

Comment: the tutorial has a for loop of 500 for 10 threads. How do I determine what this for loop size should be? I'll appreciate if you can provide some insights.

Answer (score 0):

In additions to your Thread Pool you should use a thread safe queue for allowing more work than threads available.